# How would a global vaccination campaign stop COVID-19, rather than favor new mutation?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

According to [this](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1009243/Technical_Briefing_20.pdf) report by Public Health England (p.35):

> whilst vaccination may reduce an individual’s overall risk of becoming
> infected, once they are infected there is limited difference in viral
> load (and Ct values) between those who are vaccinated and
> unvaccinated. Given they have similar Ct values, this suggests limited
> difference in infectiousness.

If this is true, how would vaccination help stop the virus?
Logic would suggest just the opposite: since vaccination does not decrease significantly infectiousness, chances for new (possibly deadlier) mutations to arise should increase.
Could someone explain which piece of data I'm missing?

Comment: @Armand thanks for your response. Could you provide the data to back up your comment? (vaccination reduces risk of becoming infected)

Comment: Armand already did, **and the quote in your question says it too**.

Comment: @BryanKrause the quote is "it may reduce ... the overall risk of becoming infected". Just because something *may* do something, doesn't mean it actually does. That's why I was asking for the data that would back up such statement.

Comment: The "may reduce" is tied to "an individual". The "while...may" construct here is not suggesting that it's possible vaccines don't reduce infection risk in a population, but in a given individual. Are you seriously asking questions about vaccination without being aware of all the efficacy trials of vaccines?

Comment: Well, vaccination does reduce total infectiousness. Because less people get infected. They say that if you are infected, you're just as infectious as an unvaccinated person who gets infected, **but if you are not infected then your infectiousness is zero**.

Answer (score 5):

As you note in your quote "vaccination may reduce [data shows it does, substantially] an individual's overall risk of becoming infected". If an individual is not infected, they are not infectious and do not spread the virus. New mutations arise in proportion to the number of people infected, so if fewer people become infected (due to the vaccine), fewer new variants are generated.

Here's one study that found "CDC COVID-19 Study Shows mRNA Vaccines Reduce Risk of Infection by 91 Percent for Fully Vaccinated People" CDC press release at https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2021/p0607-mrna-reduce-risks.html

Study is "Prevention and Attenuation of COVID-19 by BNT162b2 and mRNA-1273 Vaccines" doi: https://doi.org/10.1101/2021.06.01.21257987

Exposure to COVID would be whatever mix of variants were circulating where and when they did the tests. The test population of health workers is described in the scientific paper as being from 8 locations (roughly half in Arizona). Data was collected from mid-December 2020 through mid-April 2021. "Of 93 genetically sequenced viruses, 10 were variants of concern (8 B.1.429, 1 B.1.1.7, 1 B.1.427) and 1 was a variant of interest (P.2) (Table_S3)"

This is of course just one study, but illustrates the concept of protection against infection.

Comment: Note that all links state that vaccination **lowers the risk of** becoming infected. It doesn't stop infection completely, but it does lower the viral load and speed of viral spread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not able however to find out which covid-19 VOC this data refers to (alpha, beta, gamma, or delta). Would you know where it is mentioned?

Comment: Updated answer with variant info.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Not sure about what exactly you intended to say with your wording,This and other studies clearly show that most/many of those vaccinated are indeed protected against becoming infected at all. I think it is still unclear whether in the group of vaccinated people anyone might catch it if exposed enough times, or whether only certain individuals among the vaccinated are less protected and so they are susceptible to the "breakthrough" infections.

Comment: @Armand your first link for example, you said yourself that mRNA vaccines **reduce the risk by 91%**. That is not total protection. There is still a chance of covid infection. Granted it is small, but there is still a chance and there are double vaccinated people who have been infected.

Comment: @ChrisRogers That still seems like a non sequitur. Nothing in Armand's answer states or assumes that the risk is reduced by 100%. It's quite rare for *anything* in medicine or biology to be 100%.

Comment: @ChrisRogers The study indeed suggests that 91% of the vaccinated people are 100% protected against infection during the time period of the study (months I believe).  Perhaps some of those same people may be infected later after that time period upon repeated exposure to the COVID virus or perhaps all the infection risk is now borne by the other 9% who for some reason didn't develp full protection against the virus -- we don't know this yet. The studies are done on populations, while your statements seem to be about individuals.

Comment: @BryanKrause It wasn't intended to indicate the possibility that Armand's answer said 100% protection initially. It was just a note for others reading, as many in my social circle believe that the vaccines are supposed to provide 100% protection from infection. Armand in response did indicate the same *"This and other studies clearly show that most/many of those vaccinated are indeed protected against becoming infected at all."* That needed addressing. **All** vaccinated are provided 91% protection according to that study

Comment: @Chris Perhaps a phrasing that would fit with what you're trying to convey is that right now, a vaccinated person has no way to tell if they personally are protected against infection or not, although the chances are highly in his/her favor.